# why printing task repeated at clicking

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, onclick, todoist

in the following code when I clic once on task, it prints only once but if I press again on other task it prints twice also if I press again it prints three times,but actually I need it to print just once whenever I clic on any task

```
   const addnewtask = () => {

  let newTask = ` <div class="task">
        <h2 class="taskname">${lectureName.value}</h2>
    <h3 class="tasktime">
    <span id="hh">8</span>:
    <span id="mm">05</span>:
    <span id="ss">05</span>:
    <span id="ampm">am</span>
    </h3>
    <button class="editetask" onclick="editeTask()">Edite</button>
    </div>`
  tasks.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", newTask)

}

const editeTask = () => {
    let alltasks = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
    alltasks.forEach((task, index) => {
      task.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(index)
      })
    })
    newTask.addEventListener("click", addnewtask)
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle with your relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/ ? and explain more the issue you are facing.

Comment: Probably because every time `editetask` is executed, you iterate over *all*  existing tasks and add a new eventlistenener to each of them.